# Connecting a n device to a ac router.

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

Can you connect a wireless n device to a wireless ac router?  Looking at a new ac router and was wondering if all my n devices would connect.

Answer (score 1):

Yes they will. AC support implicitly includes N support.

2.4GHz clients will *always* use 802.11n 2.4GHz, and 802.11ac 5GHz will support 802.11n clients.

Comment: At this time, all 802.11ac-capable APs are simultaneous dual-band devices that still do 802.11b/g/n in the 2.4GHz band. I don't know of any single-band (5GHz only) 802.11ac APs, but it's possible that someone will build and sell them at some point. It's worth mentioning that if such a product were to exist, 5GHz-capable 802.11n devices would be able to join it, but any 2.4GHz-only 802.11n devices would not be able to.

Comment: Yup. The short answer is "Yes, They will" but I have a minimum character count. I do believe 5ghz stuff is compatible back to 802.11A as well, but I've never really tested it.